# How to change the language setting of xcode 8.3.3 (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I found several topics on this application but none works for me. I would like my **Swift3 project** in **Xcode 8.3.3** to be in French.

1) I added a localization in main page

2) I then change the language in the info.plist file

3) I chose French for my mainStoryBoard

Often I see you need to edit a file but I never have the file mentioned in the tutorial

When I run the simulator I still have the keyboard in English how to change it?

Comment: firstly change the language of phone

Comment: We do it where pls

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Change the project language:
[image]

Comment: I added the French but nothing

Answer (score 1):

You can go to edit schema in project target at the top. And select application language under option tab. Then run the application. It will launch the application in selected language.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just did but still the english calvier grrr